# Left Join with Group By

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I am using PostgreSQL 9.4.

I have a table of `workouts`. Users can create multiple `results` for each `workout`, and a `result` has a `score`.

Given a list of workout_ids and two user_ids, I want to return the best score for each workout for each user. If the user does not have a result for that workout, I want to return a padded/null result.

```
SELECT "results".*, "workouts".* 
FROM "results" LEFT JOIN "workouts" ON "workouts"."id" = "results"."workout_id" 
WHERE (
  (user_id, workout_id, score) IN 
  (SELECT user_id, workout_id, MAX(score) 
    FROM results WHERE user_id IN (1, 2) AND workout_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
    GROUP BY user_id, workout_id)
)
```

In this query, the left join is acting as an inner join; I'm not getting any padding if the user has not got a result for the workout. This query should always return six rows, regardless of how many results exist.

Example data:

```
results
user_id | workout_id | score 
-----------------------------
      1 |          1 |     10
      1 |          3 |     10
      1 |          3 |     15
      2 |          1 |      5

Desired result:

results.user_id | results.workout_id | max(results.score) | workouts.name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
              1 |                  1 |                 10 | Squat
              1 |                  2 |               null | Bench
              1 |                  3 |                 15 | Deadlift
              2 |                  1 |                  5 | Squat
              2 |                  2 |               null | Bench
              2 |                  3 |               null | Deadlift
```

Answer (score 4):

The where filters out your NULL values, so that is why the result is not what you expect.

Joinint the WHERE clause results instead of filter the where clause results.

```
SELECT "results".*, "workouts".*,"max_score".*
FROM "results" 
LEFT JOIN "workouts" ON "workouts"."id" = "results"."workout_id"
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, workout_id, MAX(score) 
    FROM results WHERE user_id IN (1, 2) AND workout_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
    GROUP BY user_id, workout_id) max_score ON workouts.workout_id=max_score.workout_id;
```

You need to alter the SELECT to get the correct columns.

Comment: This returns rows for me where the user_id IN (1, 2) AND workout_id IN (1, 2, 3) constraints are not adhered to.

Comment: So the join should be on user_id and workout_id against the results table instead?

Comment: I think the left join of `max_score` needs to be on `(workout_id,user_id,score)`

Comment: @FuzzyTree : You are probably right. The example data was added after the answer. Ben is now hopefully on the right track to get it finished himself :)

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1, 2)
       u.user_id
     , w.id AS workout_id
     , r.score
     , w.name AS workout_name
FROM   workouts w
CROSS  JOIN (VALUES (1), (2)) u(user_id)
LEFT   JOIN  results r ON r.workout_id = w.id
                      AND r.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE  w.id IN (1, 2, 3)
ORDER  BY 1, 2, r.score DESC NULLS LAST;
```

#### Step by step explanation

1. Form a *complete* Cartesian product of given workouts and users.
   Assuming the given workouts *always* exist.
   Assuming that *not all* given users have results for all given workouts.
2. `LEFT JOIN` to `results`. All conditions go into the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN`, not into the `WHERE` clause, which would exclude `(workout_id, user_id)` combinations that have no result. See:

   - [Rails includes query with conditions not returning all results from left table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621636/rails-includes-query-with-conditions-not-returning-all-results-from-left-table/24621733#24621733)
3. Finally pick the best result per `(user_id, workout_id)` with `DISTINCT ON`. While being at it, produce the desired sort order. See:

   - [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Depending on the size of tables and data distribution there may be faster solutions. See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

#### Simple version

If all you want is the maximum `score` for each `(user_id, workout_id)` combination, there is simple version:

```sql
SELECT user_id, workout_id, max(r.score) AS score
FROM        unnest('{1,2}'::int[])   u(user_id)
CROSS  JOIN unnest('{1,2,3}'::int[]) w(workout_id)
LEFT   JOIN results r USING (user_id, workout_id)
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=973f2e5bedf83796a20868062673d0df)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4425a/1)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

How about using `distinct on` or `row_number()`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.user_id, r.workout_id) r.*, w.* 
FROM "results" r LEFT JOIN
     "workouts" w
     ON "w."id" = r."workout_id" 
WHERE r.user_id IN (1, 2) AND r.workout_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
ORDER BY r.user_id, r.workout_id, score desc;
```

The `row_number()` equivalent requires a subquery:

```
SELECT rw.*
FROM (SELECT r.*, w.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, workout_id order by score desc) as seqnum 
      FROM "results" r LEFT JOIN
           "workouts" w
           ON "w."id" = r."workout_id" 
      WHERE r.user_id IN (1, 2) AND r.workout_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
     ) rw
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

You should choose the columns more judiciously than using a `*`.  The subquery might return errors in the case of duplicate column names.

EDIT:

You need to generate the rows first, and then the results for each.  Here is one method, building on the second query:

```
SELECT u.user_id, w.workout_id, rw.score, rw.name
FROM (SELECT 1 as user_id UNION ALL SELECT 2) u CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 1 as workout_id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) w LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT r.*, w.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, workout_id order by score desc) as seqnum 
      FROM "results" r LEFT JOIN
           "workouts" w
           ON "w."id" = r."workout_id" 
      WHERE r.user_id IN (1, 2) AND r.workout_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
     ) rw
     ON rw.user_id = u.user_id and rw.workout_id = w.workout_id and
        rw.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Apologies if I misunderstood your answer, but both of these queries only returned two rows, rather than the desired six (2 user_ids x 3 workout_ids = 6 rows needed). I will annotate my original question with some sample data and the desired result to make it clearer.

Comment: @BenSmith . . . My misunderstanding.  I thought the best was per user, not per user/workout.